# Finding all the elements that are in the right of current position in an array that meets the specific condition?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Let's suppose our current index is `i` and we have an array `arr` of length `n`.
condition which is given to us is`arr[i] > 2*arr[j]`where `j` belongs from `[i+1,n-1]` and for every valid position `i` `[0<=i<n]` , we find to find the count of number of pairs that satisfies the given condition.

```
Constraints:
1 <= N <= 10^5 
1 <= arr[i] <= 10^9

Time Limit: 1sec

Sample Input 1:
10 = n
1 3 2 6 2 7 4 2 3 1 = arr
Sample Output 1:
9

Sample Input 2:
5 = n 
2 4 3 5 1 = arr
Sample Output 2:
3
```

The required time complexity is O(nlog n) , can anyone suggest me the valid solution to the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this as follows using Java's TreeMap.

- Go through each element and insert element into a treemap ( uses a Red-Black tree behind the scenes ) and update the frequency of occurrence of element as the value.
- Now look for the portion of the map that has keys greater than 2*current_element.
- Get frequency of each element in the portion of the map and add it to your result.

Complexity should be O(n*log(n)) because insertion in RB tree is log(n) and looking for portion of the map is log(n) and you do it for each element. But it could be worse than that if you have lot of duplicates.

Code in Java is :

```
   private static int getCount(int[] a) {
     int count = 0;
     TreeMap<Integer, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
     for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
      
       if ( treeMap.containsKey(a[i])) {
         treeMap.put(a[i], treeMap.get(a[i]) + 1);
       } else {
         treeMap.put(a[i], 1);
       }
       NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> m = treeMap.tailMap(2*a[i], false);
       for ( Integer key : m.keySet() ) {
         count += m.get(key);
       }
     }
     return count;
  }
```